Undefined behavior of BlocProvider
I decided to use bloc's constructs inside the build() function of all screens and encountered undefined behavior.
I have several blocs: ThemeBloc, AuthBloc, NotesBloc. ThemeBloc and NotesBloc work fine, but AuthBloc can't be added to BuildContext as I understood.
Application.dart:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeBloc()..add(SetInitialTheme()),
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeBloc, bool>(
        builder: (context, isDarkTheme) {
          return MaterialApp(
              theme: isDarkTheme ? createDarkTheme() : createLightTheme(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              initialRoute: 'auth/login',
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case 'auth/login':
                    return NNoteRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
                      settings: settings,
                    );
                  case 'auth/register':
                    return NNoteRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
                      settings: settings,
                    );
                  case 'notes':
                    return NNoteRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const NotesScreen(),
                        settings: settings);
                }
                return null;
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

LoginScreen.dart:
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => AuthBloc(RepositoryModule.authRepository()),
        child: ...); // A child uses the context to get access to AuthBloc. Also the child has a route to NotesScreen
  }

NotesScreen.dart:
class NotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _NotesScreenState createState() => _NotesScreenState();
}

class _NotesScreenState extends State<NotesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => NotesBloc(RepositoryModule.localNotesRepository())
        ..add(const NotesStarted()),
      child: ...); // A child has widgets that use NotesBloc
  }

The strange behavior is that NotesBloc works correctly, but it is created exactly as in other screens.
I noticed a special feature, if I make the creation of AuthBloc in Application.dart, then everything works correctly. However, if I put NotesBloc also in Application, it is not recognized in NotesScreen.dart in BuildContext.
I assume that the problem is in passing BuildContext. However, the signature of the screen switching function is the same everywhere: Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('notes')
There is an error of AuthBloc: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthBloc> above this LoginScreen Widget
Please explain how this issue can be resolved.

In your LoginScreen.dart did you create child from another widget or you wrote your ui code directly in the child of LoginScreen?

can you provide both login screen and notes screen?

When you define BlocProvider for AuthBloc in LoginScreen widget, You can only access AuthBloc in LoginScreen children, not anywhere else. Pay attention that you can't use AuthBloc directly in LoginScreen body and you should define other widgets as children of LoginScreen.
